# How to capture prompt from terminal using Tcl or how can I match prompt with color code?

Tags: terminal, tcl, system-administration

I want to capture prompt of a remote device.

```
 -regexp {[\$\#]\s*$} {
       # capture the prompt  
 }
```

"[\$#]\s*$" does not work for prompt with color codes.

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d` to enable verbose debugging output, and show us where the match fails. Expect should show you exactly what the prompt looks like.

Comment: One technique I sometimes use is to explicitly set the prompt upon login `spawn ssh ...; send "PS1='> '\r"; expect -re {> $}`

Answer (score 0):

Colour codes are sent as escape sequences in the character stream. As such, if you have them there you need to match them. Each escape sequence is the ESC character (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, `^[`, `\u001b`) followed by various characters terminated with a `;` (well, that's the colour setting ones; there are others, and they're somewhat complicated). While yes, you could match these with a more complicated regular expression, it's enormously easier to set the prompt to something simple that you control.

```
# ...
expect "ssword: "
send $password\r
# Note, *NO* expect at this point as matching it is hard
send "PS1='> '\r"
expect -regexp {> $}
```

Coloured prompts are nice enough for people, but they're awkward for scripting. Overriding will make your life much easier. (You might also try setting the terminal to a terminal type that doesn't support colours.)

Comment: I need this script to work on various platforms including *nix, windows and etc. "PS1='> '\r" will not work on all of these platforms. Do I just need to capture the prompt instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have found success using ANSI escape codes like this:

```
set NO_COLOR "\033"
set RED_COLOR "\[0;31m"
expect {
    "${RED_COLOR} here is red input text ${NO_COLOR}" { puts "matched!" }
}

set NO_COLOR_REGEX "\033\\\[0m"
set RED_COLOR_REGEX "\033\\\[0;31m"
expect {
    -re "${RED_COLOR_REGEX} here is red input text ${NO_COLOR_REGEX}" { puts "matched!" }
}

set RED_OUTPUT "\033\[0;31m"
set NO_COLOR_OUTPUT "\033\[0m"
puts "${RED_OUTPUT} here is some colored output text ${NO_COLOR_OUTPUT}"
```